# WordPress Custom Post query else data

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I recently developed a *Wordpress* theme, this theme has little bit complex custom post type.

Below is my *custom post* query code. I would like kind of a `else` content whenever the request doesn't return any post. Its currently just blank.
I am not a *PHP* developer though, would someone give me a hand adding such a alternative content ?
Thank you.

```
<div class="front_page_deal_holder">
    <?php
    // get the currently queried taxonomy term, for use later in the template file
    $term = get_queried_object();

    //second query - posts

    // Define the query
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'product_cat' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        // output the term name in a heading tag                
        echo'<h1>All Products about '. $term->name . '</h1>';
        echo'<div class="row">';           
            // Start the Loop
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <a style="display:block;text-decoration:none" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="single_front_sec">
                        <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'post-image'); ?>
                        <img class="post_thumb_cus" src="<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>" alt="Product Image">
                        <h2 class="featured_product_heading">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
                        <span class="offer_note"><p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Offer Note', true); ?></p></span>
                        <div class="vew_d_button_holder">
                            <a class="view_d_button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <!-- row -->
        <div class="my_Custom_pagination">
            <?php   wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); ?>
        </div>

    <?php } // end of check for query having posts

    // use reset postdata to restore orginal query
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>

    <?php include_once('top-categories.php'); ?>

    <!--====  Top catogory section  ====-->

    <!-- front deal closed -->
</div>
```

Comment: This question seems unclear.  Provide an example of what you want, what you have and why it's not working.

Comment: Your code is hard to read the way it is formatted. Cleaning that up would help you get an answer.

Comment: I have posted else part with your code please review

Comment: I wanted to add an else data in this loop, @ravipatel gave me the solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
elseif(!$query->have_posts()){//HTML here}
```

or

```
else{ //HTML here}
```

right after the end of check for your query , if you want to follow an OOP rule to make your code cleaner , move everything into a function inside function.php file and call the function there instead

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please edit my code and solve it, for a details solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="front_page_deal_holder">
    <?php
    // get the currently queried taxonomy term, for use later in the template file
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'product_cat' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        echo'<h1>All Products about '. $term->name . '</h1>';
        echo'<div class="row">';           
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <a style="display:block;text-decoration:none" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="single_front_sec">
                        <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'post-image'); ?>
                        <img class="post_thumb_cus" src="<?php echo $featured_img_url ?>" alt="Product Image">
                        <h2 class="featured_product_heading">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </h2>
                        <span class="offer_note"><p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Offer Note', true); ?></p></span>
                        <div class="vew_d_button_holder">
                            <a class="view_d_button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Details</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="my_Custom_pagination">
            <?php   wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php }else{


                // Add your code here for else part

        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    <?php include_once('top-categories.php'); ?>
</div>
```